# Moving docs WITH version history

Tags: versioning, document-library

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you move a document with its version history to a new library?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1278/how-can-you-move-a-document-with-its-version-history-to-a-new-library)

Tom, were you ever able to move documents WITH version histories from one folder to another?  I see several ideas, but you never confirmed you were able to accomplish it.  I'm trying to do the same thing and the Explorer View MOVE isn't working for me either.

Thanks,
Randy

Comment: Are you referencing this question? http://www.sharepointoverflow.com/questions/1278/how-can-you-move-a-document-with-its-version-history-to-a-new-library

Comment: if so, Tom did confirm: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1278/how-can-you-move-a-document-with-its-version-history-to-a-new-library/1322#1322