# Is there a way to move files with the SP Object model in MOSS whilst retaining meta data?

Tags: 2007, powershell, site-collection

Is there a way in SharePoint 2007 to move a file from one document library to another, in the same site collection programatically? I made [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516866/move-files-between-document-libraries-in-the-same-site-collection-2) about this on StackOverflow, with a bounty not too long ago but had no success. I was hoping this community might have some more insight.

Comment: See this related question: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10823/how-can-i-move-a-document-from-one-directory-to-another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
// Get your source and destination libraries
SPList source = web.GetList(web.ServerRelativeUrl + @"/SourceDocLib");
SPList destination = web.GetList(web.ServerRelativeUrl + @"/DestinationDocLib");

// Get the collection of items to move, use source.GetItems(SPQuery) if you want a subset
SPListItemCollection items = items = source.Items;

// Get the root folder of the destination we'll use this to add the files
SPFolder folder = web.GetFolder(destination.RootFolder.Url);

// Now to move the files and the metadata
foreach (SPListItem item in items)
{   
    //Get the file associated with the item     
    SPFile file = item.File;
    // Create a new file in the destination library with the same properties
    SPFile newFile = folder.Files.Add(folder.Url + "/" +file.Name, file.OpenBinary(),file.Properties,true);
    // Optionally copy across the created/modified metadata                        
    SPListItem newItem = newFile.Item;
    newItem["Editor"] = item["Editor"];
    newItem["Modified"] = item["Modified"];
    newItem["Author"] = item["Author"];
    newItem["Created"] = item["Created"];

    // UpdateOverwriteVersion() will preserve the metadata added above. 
    newItem.UpdateOverwriteVersion();                              
}
```

If you want to delete the originals as well use `for (int i = items.Count -1; i > -1 ; i--)` instead of the `foreach` to iterate backwards through the collection and `items[i].Recycle();` or `items[i].Delete();` to recycle or delete the original after you have moved it.

To move the items into subfolders replace the line `SPFolder folder = web.GetFolder(destination.RootFolder.Url);` with code similar to the following:

```
// Set the name of the new destination subfolder
string newFolderName = "Sub Folder 1";
// Try to get the new subfolder so we can test to see if it exists and if not create it
SPFolder folder = web.GetFolder(destination.RootFolder.Url + "/" + newFolderName);
if (!folder.Exists)
{
    // Add the new folder
    SPListItem folderItem = destination.Folders.Add("", SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder, newFolderName);
    folderItem.SystemUpdate();
    // Get the folder after creating it
    folder = web.GetFolder(destination.RootFolder.Url + "/" + newFolderName);
                            Console.WriteLine(@"Created folder ""{0}""", folder.Url);
}
```

I'll post this answer with your original post on StackOverflow as well in case people look there first.

Comment: Thanks. It's a public holiday here today so I don't have a test machine available but I'll try this at work tomorrow and see how it goes :D

Comment: This works great - however is there a way to make it move items in subfolders separately? Currently it moves them out of the subfolder (folder within the document library) and places them back in the top level of the new location

Comment: @Michael I've updated the answer with code to add items to subfolders.