# With Microsoft's web interface alone – without third party products – can an end user move a folder in SharePoint Server 2010?

Tags: web

I see an option to cut a folder, but at the destination:

- no option to paste.

I can't find an option to move.

I searched and browsed the help that's integral to the server.

## Question

Please: **can an end user move a folder?** If so, how?

### Clarification

Without Microsoft Windows – with the web interface alone.

Without third party add-ons – with SharePoint alone.

Comment: If Microsoft's normal web interface to SharePoint lacks this functionality – if as an end user (not a SharePoint administrator) I can not move a folder – that simple answer "can't be done" may be acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the out of the box (OOTB) end user interface to SharePoint:

- it is impossible to move a file or folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "Open with Windows Explorer" option available on a document library. Just use the options from the right click context menu.

Comment: Without Microsoft Windows– with the web interface only. I'll add to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these related questions:

- [How can you move a document with its version history to a new library?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1278/how-can-you-move-a-document-with-its-version-history-to-a-new-library/1292#1292)
- [How can I move a document from one directory to another?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10823/how-can-i-move-a-document-from-one-directory-to-another/11839#11839)

Comment: With SharePoint (not with third-party add-ons). I clarified the question.