# Item transfer/copy between lists - UI only approach

Tags: list, item

I have to Copy / Move items from a list to another existing one 
here's the first one :

[image]

and here's the target one:

[image]

the columns have the same name, same type...etc

How can I achieve that **without writing custom code**? I would like to use only out of the box functionalities.

Comment: Save the original as a template with content and provision a new list off it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the [SP List Item Copy](http://splistkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SP%20List%20Item%20Copy).

SP List Item Copy enables a user to copy SharePoint list items. User can use this feature easily via Ribbon UI

Comment: Does the tool manage copy operations between different lists? The documentation only show a copy created in the same list.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily using Content and Structure feature. Just append _layouts/sitemanager.aspx to the site utl and you can see various lists in the page. Select the list and then the item to be moved. Click on ECB menu and then move the item to destination list.

Comment: @Nadeem...i already tried this but unfortunatly and i don't know why...when i move the items...it copying the column and create a new one (even if the column already exists) :s

and the moved item doen't have the new column when i want to edit it

Comment: This post may help you to perform your task the other way like datasheet view. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c5984714-218b-49a3-91e9-5f8d361e1853/moving-list-items-between-folders?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy

Comment: thanks but nope :( doesn't working...i can't even copying items

Comment: i'll have no choice to install vs on the server and do that with code

Comment: If it is a one time thing then you can perhaps try the trial version of this tool from boost solutions http://www.boostsolutions.com/sharepoint-list-transfer.html

Answer (score 0):

Similar questions has been answered before in this forum.

- [How can you move a document with its version history to a new library?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1278/how-can-you-move-a-document-with-its-version-history-to-a-new-library/1292#1292)
- [How can I move a document from one directory to another?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10823/how-can-i-move-a-document-from-one-directory-to-another/11839#11839)

Comment: You are talking about library and documents...
i'am talking about sharepoint lists and items

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with PowerShell or with a workflow?

Comment: yep maybe but workflows doesn't have option to copy from one list to other one ... is there something with powershell?

Comment: Hmmm - I do most of my workflows with Nintex and it is certainly possible there.  As for PowerShell - here is an example http://adicodes.com/copy-or-replace-list-items-in-powershell/