# Move Document Library item across sites

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you move a document with its version history to a new library?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1278/how-can-you-move-a-document-with-its-version-history-to-a-new-library)

I've done R&D a lot on "How to move document library item across sites" and find the following solutions;

1. Add source document library item to destination site document
   library but in this case item version history and metadata create
   problem.
2. Found link related to use SPExport and SPImport but SPExport did not run. Code used for moving the document library item.

Any idea or comment would be appreciated regarding this critical issue.

Answer (score 2):

Moving documents across sites with full fidelity is not possible OOB in SharePoint 2007/2010. You will need to code your own solution or employ a third-party solution. My company develops and sells the product [CopyMove for SharePoint](http://www.sharepointproducts.com) that can copy and move documents, items and folders across sites with full fidelity. The product is designed for end-users but there is also an API for use with custom applications.

Answer (score 0):

Those are the two best methods short of something highly customized or a 3rd party solution.