# Copy files between sites with version history (powershell, SP2010)

Tags: 2010, powershell, versioning, version-history

I can copy a file from one site to another using

```
$SPFolder_Destination.Files.Add("Filename.ext", $SPFile_Source.OpenBinary(), $false)
```

This does not preserve version history.

I think I could possibly [download all versions](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/95073/powershell-for-downloading-documents-with-versions) and then [upload as new versions](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/04/28/weekend-scripter-use-powershell-to-upload-a-sharepoint-file-version.aspx), but as you can see that is quite a mess.

Does anyone know any easier ways to transfer/copy a file between sites (on the same server) which maintains version history? I'm using SP2010.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it mandatory to use powershell? Can't you use server object model?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but doesn't Powershell use this object model anyway?

Comment: You can use the following PS script to copy/migrate files from one library to other . Please follow the guidelines and run ps with your server url. https://github.com/alimughalx/CopySharePointFilesWithMetaDataAndVersionHistory Hopefully this may resolve your issue in case of PS. Please mark the answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SPExportObject object and SPImport object seem to provide what I need.

[This technet blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2007/08/30/deep-dive-into-the-sharepoint-content-deployment-and-migration-api-part-1.aspx) provided the solution in C#, which I translated to Powershell.

Unfortunately at that point I ran into the same problems as [the user in this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/95309/how-do-i-migrate-a-document-library-and-just-the-documents-with-powershell). Like him, I could not get the event handler to work correctly and like him, I bit the bullet and implemented the entire thing in C#.

It is now working (more or less) as desired.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is by design, the version history of a document is relative to its original document library. When you move the document to another library, it is considered as a new document there, when the metadata is copied, it changes minor version. There is no Non-coding solution for this.

Also look at below blog to copy files with version history using Server side object model:

http://sharepointvenividivici.typepad.com/sharepoint-customization/2011/06/maintain-file-version-history-when-movingcopying-files-between-sharepoint-sites.html

You can try with its powershell equivalent code if you want to acheive this by powershell only.