# SPFileCollection.Add for copying file cross SharePoint Farm

Tags: migration, document-migration

I have requirement in which I need to copy documents with there version history and created by ,created on , modified by , modified on. I am able to achieve this for copying from one site collection to other with the help of  `SPFileCollection.Add` . How can I achieve this copying from one SharePoint farm to Other.

Comment: How do you choose these documents? Are all the documents in one list?

Comment: Similar question here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1278/how-can-you-move-a-document-with-its-version-history-to-a-new-library

Comment: Yes they are in one document library

Answer (score 0):

If you have similar SharePoint version with the two farms then use below approach.

**SPExport/SPImport** using this we can have similar version history new farm it will not disturb the Document version history.

Ref : http://sadomovalex.blogspot.in/2011/09/using-spexportspimport-for-copying.html

Comment: I have to from 2007 to 2013. I do have 2010 as well so from 2007 to 2010 and from 2010 to 2013 will also help.

Comment: The above approach will not work, we should have to maintain similar version, otherwise we have to update each and every export file version like 12.0.0 to 14.0.0, but it's not a good practice to migration.

Comment: Please let me know if you find any solution for it. Thanks

Comment: If you want to maintain file version history then my suggestion would be try migration tools, if you doesn't care about version then use power-shell to export and import process we will maintain the last version in new system.

Comment: I have to maintain version history with created by ,on and modified by ,on info. I am trying to achieve this pragmatically or any other way.Yes , I am keeping migration tool as a last option in handy. Can you suggest any migration tool ?

Comment: We have used Metalogix one of our project http://www.metalogix.com/Products/Content-Matrix.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I use Content Deployment Wizard. URL : https://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/ 
 . if you need to copy documents based on criterias, use CDW to copy them to a another site collection and then you copy them to the target location

P.S. If you use content types, CDW will also copy them, along with site columns

Comment: I have to copy from 2007 to 2013.