# Move File With Versions from one library to another

Tags: version

I am trying to move documents to a new libarary but the version history is lost when I do....any ideas?

Comment: what is ur sharepoint version?

Comment: Is versioning enabled in your other library? And how are you trying to move items?

Comment: Yes...versioning is enabled.  I have tried to move them in explorer and drag and drop.

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1278/how-can-you-move-a-document-with-its-version-history-to-a-new-library