# Move files across site collections with version history using explorer view

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-library, document-migration

I am trying to move files (cut paste) from one site collection to another site collection using explorer view (Mapped N/W Drive) both lib has same content type (common template) the metadata is moving but the version history is getting deleted. Am I missing something ??

I need to move more than 6000 files of more than 100GB so save site as template include content or Export-SPWeb not going to work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the destination library has versioning enabled. And try using drag and Drop. See this for more information: [How can you move a document with its version history to a new library?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1278/how-can-you-move-a-document-with-its-version-history-to-a-new-library)

Comment: Version history is enabled. I tried using Drag and Drop as well as Cut Paste but still the result is negative.

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't work across site collections. Can you test if drag/drop works with libraries in same site collection for you?

Comment: I have tested drag/drop doesn't work with libraries in same site collection also. It creating a minor version 0.1 always. Added screenshot for reference.

Answer (score 0):

This pretty much doesn't work at all with drag/drop.  In essence, SharePoint thinks you're creating a "new" file and is unaware of where it's coming from.  Saving as a template is not much of an option due to the number of files and size.  Your best bet (I'm afraid) is to purchase a migration tool which will do the job quite well.  ShareGate has one that's good as well as Dell SharePoint Content Migrator.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because Explorer View (Mapped Network Drive) is a WebDAV connection, which has nothing to do with SharePoint persé, so can not handle all SharePoint Metadata.
*note: WebDAV relies on ActiveX technology, so is only available in the 32bit IE browser*

A workaround is to use SharePoint default values and/or Documentset capabilities to set default metadata values and upload your files in batches with the same metadata.
But you won't get the Versioning metadata accross as essentials new files are created.

#### 3rd party tools

Alex Dove has compiled a matrix of 3rd party tools available

http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/sharepoint-comparison-matrix-for-3rd-party-migration-tools

[image]