# Move documents from one site another

Tags: development, document-library, document, metadata, version-history

We are using SP 2013 on-prem, and I am writing some functionality in c# to move document from one site to another, within the same site collection.

I have read a litte about the SPFile.MoveTo, but it's samples are a bit confusing: some say they can only copy, and some that they can only move files within the same site; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.moveto.aspx

I am looking for samples where I can move a document from one document library to a document library on another site, and keep the metadata and versions log.

Comment: This question has already been asked and answered a few times in this forum. See http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1278/how-can-you-move-a-document-with-its-version-history-to-a-new-library

Comment: The SPFile.Moveto can only be used to move files inside the same SharePoint site. I need to move the document in another site, and am looking for samples where that has been achieved.

Comment: Hi Lars. I want to buy your product, but I don't need the graphical stuff or wsp, only need the powershell commandlets and API I can use. Is that possible? I don't want to install wsp we are not going to use etc.

Comment: Ilyas - thanks! This is not the right forum for sales and support. Have replied to your email with answers.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, the "Send to" sends a copy to another location so you can do it again and again to distribute a copy of the master file to other sites.

Is this a one time move or will you need to do it over and over?

Sometimes a simplee copy / paste from each library's windows explorer works for users. (unless your trying to do something more complex)

SharePoint designer might have some actions to copy a document to a specified path if you want to go that route.

[Records center](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Create-a-Records-Center-6BF1488B-62A8-486C-90DD-54B6BCCE4B3A) sites are also rather sophisticated with routing documents to different parts of SharePoint based on rules, content types and other info.

Comment: I have checked all the options, and we can not do it by using the GUI. We have a heavily customized solution. This will be done using a workflow, and we need to move, not copy. I am looking for some samples where documents are moved from one subsite to another.