# How can i move files including its version history from one document library to another?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, document-library

I am using a workflow action "copy item" and "delete item from current list" which copies the files from one document library to another but when the files are copied over to a different library, it removes all the version histories.

I know there is a manual way to move item using "Open With Explorer" which moves files with its version history but we don't want to use that and want something that moves files with its version history automatically...

Any Help Would Be Greatly Appreciated.

Thanks You

Comment: As the Open with explorer -functionality is there, you can do it all in PowerShell, automatically or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a workflow that makes a **Copy** then it will not keep its version history. It will only keep it if you **Move** the files.

There has been as [similar question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1278/how-can-you-move-a-document-with-its-version-history-to-a-new-library) asked