# Copy document Library

Tags: document-library

I have a document library in a web application, I need to copy all the items of this document library in other web application document library. The document library also consist some lookup field. I am trying to do this by creating a console application. How should I proceed. Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: Site Settings/Site Content and Structure is good for copying all items.  Also see this popular post for info:   https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1278/how-can-you-move-a-document-with-its-version-history-to-a-new-library      I don't know a way of copying the lookup fields, you might need to re-do them.

Comment: In your console application, after migrating the library to other web application, get the lookup field's schema xml and update it with the correct lookup url. Finally set it back and do `field.Update()`. This should work.