# How to overwrite version of a file using CSOM?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, csom, versioning

When I check in as a major version or minor version, it creates the new version as a major. Below is the code:

```
private static void UploadFiles(string sourceFileUrl, Folder targetFolder, string fileName,ClientContext clientContext,ClientContext destinationContext, bool bolMajorVersion)
    {

        FileCreationInformation targetFileVersionCreationInfo = new FileCreationInformation();
        targetFileVersionCreationInfo.Overwrite = true;
        try
        {
            WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(sourceFileUrl);
            request.Credentials = clientContext.Credentials;
            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    byte[] verBuffer = new byte[32768];
                    using (MemoryStream versionMS = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        int read;
                        while ((read = stream.Read(verBuffer, 0, verBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                        {
                            versionMS.Write(verBuffer, 0, read);
                        }
                        versionMS.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        targetFileVersionCreationInfo.ContentStream = versionMS;
                        destinationContext.RequestTimeout = System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite;
                        targetFileVersionCreationInfo.Url = targetFolder.ServerRelativeUrl+ "/" + fileName;
                        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File targetVersionFile = targetFolder.Files.Add(targetFileVersionCreationInfo);

                        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = targetVersionFile;
                        //Checkout if checked in
                        destinationContext.Load(file);

                        destinationContext.ExecuteQuery();

                        if (file.CheckOutType == CheckOutType.None)
                        {
                            file.CheckOut();
                        }
                        //ListItem lstItem = file.ListItemAllFields;
                        //clientContext.Load(lstItem);
                        //clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                        if (bolMajorVersion)
                        {

                            file.CheckIn("Uploaded through portal", CheckinType.MajorCheckIn);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Overwrite to avoid creating new version
                            file.CheckIn("Uploaded through portal", CheckinType.MinorCheckIn);
                        }
                        destinationContext.ExecuteQuery();
                        //  destinationContext.ExecuteQuery();





                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //handle exception
        }
    }
```

The file initially upload with version 0.1 after check in as a major version, it creates new version 1.0 and also keep version 0.1. I need to overwrite this 0.1 version file.

Any help should be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The targetFolder.Files.Add is checking the file out too. So before you are going to overwrite the file, **first** retrieve itwith a try catch around it (in case it doesn't exist) and **check it out**. After that add the file with targetFolder.Files.Add(), do something with metadata if you like and check it in.

Comment: Got to rectify this a little. This does not work when the file doesn't exist. In that case you might indeed want to use SystemUpdate, like @GVIrish mentioned, but in my case that doesn't work as I still got to support SP2013 for the application I'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `SystemUpdate()` on the SPListItem attached to your file before you call `ExecuteQuery()`.  So it should be something like

```
file.Item.SystemUpdate();
destinationContext.Load(file);
destinationContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

You may have to play with the order of the statements a bit, but I think SystemUpdate() is the function you're looking for.