# Copy files from a document library without losing Version History

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, version-history, move, copy

I have the next scenario:

I have to select a particular version from a file from a Source `Document Library` and copy that file along with it's version history.
All previous versions before the selected one (same as move function) and metadata, must be copied to the Destination `Document Library`.
I, also, have to maintain the file in the source document library.

I made one solution:

When a file is created or updated along with `REST API` for versioning so every time I make a new version the file is copied and I have version and other metadata as columns in the destination, but that's not what I need.

Any idea how to solve this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no workaround to solve this.

As you said, Copy files will not maintain all version history, only the latest version is copied. To copy earlier versions, you need to restore and copy each one.

Answer (score 0):

Just **move** *(drag & drop and **not copy**)* a file in Explorer View from one document library to another, and it will keep all of previous versions!

Also check if both libraries have versioning enabled, which in default is.

Reference: [How can you move a document with its version history to a new library?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1278/how-can-you-move-a-document-with-its-version-history-to-a-new-library?rq=1)